# Adding together nested data () object values with identical keys in VueJS Components

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, addition

I have a bunch of values with identical keys that are nested within neighboring objects within the `data() {}` return of my VueJS component.

example:

```
data() { 
  return {
     foo: {
         userScore: 10,
         computerScore: 5
     },
     bar: {
         userScore: 22,
         computerScore: 100
     }
  }
}
```

What would be the best/most performant way to add `bar.userScore` and `foo.userScore` without having to write out the full JSON route each time? (The component I am writing for this has about 40+ of these scores so doing rote addition in computed seems a bit odd)

Is there a way to access these identical properties, such as `*.userScore` ?

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `reduce` to get a summation:

```
const sum = Object.keys(this.$data).reduce((sum, key) => {
  if (this.$data[key].hasOwnProperty('userScore')) {
    return (sum + this.$data[key].userScore)
  }
  return sum
}, 0)
```